# Помогите с запросом: Разделение событий на первичное и повторные

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица посещений, что-то вроде:

```
id, data-time, id_doctor, id_pacient, id_usluga, cena
```

Задача составить запрос, так, чтобы определить какая услуга за день первая, а какая повторная, да так, чтобы не сильно требовало ресурсов.

Comment: услуга конкретного пациента у конкретного доктора? или какая услуга для пациента повторная, но у разных докторов?

Comment: один и тотже пациент, доктор один и тотже. услуг несколько.

Comment: Вы бы написали, что пытались сделать, что не получилось. С примером данных и ожидаемым результатом. Можно добавить ссылку на sqlfiddle и было бы вообще идеально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *,
       row_number() over(partition by id_pacient, cast(data-time as Date)
                             order by data-time) RNUM
  from Table
```

Функция row_number() подсчитывает строки в *окне*, в порядке указанной сортировки. Параметры *окна* задаются в предложении over(). В данном случае строки будут посчитаны в пределах одного пациента и одного дня и отсортированы по времени. Таким образом у первой услуги за день RNUM будет равен 1, у повторных услуг он будет больше 1 (порядковый номер услуги за день).

Comment: спасибо. то что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос нечетко поставлен.

Самый простой пример (работает очень быстро)

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
ORDER BY id_doctor ASC, id_pacient ASC, data_time ASC
```

В итоге будет список, отсортированный по докторам, потом пациентам и потом дате-времени от более раннего к более позднему.

Если нужен конкретный день, то

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE date_time > DATETIME(дата текущего дня) AND date_time < (дата следующего дня)
ORDER BY id_doctor ASC, id_pacient ASC, data_time ASC
```

Или имелось в виду что-то другое?